# Capybara/Rspec tests will not run together, but work fine on their own?

Tags: selenium, rspec, capybara

So I have a few rspec tests, and i've been able to run them individually just fine without an issue (They are using Selenium as their driver).

However when I try to run multiples of them OR put both of them in the same file I get an error:

```
"     Failure/Error: visit ('/')
     ArgumentError:
       rack-test requires a rack application, but none was given"
```

I have an idea of why this is happening, since my tests are all written from a standalone point of view, they all have `visit ('/')` at the beginning of each test.

When a capybara test "ends" at literally the 'end' at the end of the 'describe' block...does it not close the browser? Or if im writing a test suite should it all assume that the browser is never closed?

The weird thing though, for instance if I run: `rspec --tag type:feature spec/features/*`  I get the same issue (but they are each separate files, so you would think the browser would close, also each test is tagged with :feature so it should (and does) attempt to run them all. It just fails after the first one)

Comment: Any luck with any of [the existing questions that mention this error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rack-test+requires+a+rack+application%2C+but+none+was+given)? If not, better post some configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error message you specify mentions rack-test, not all of your tests are using selenium as the driver.  It sounds like you're not testing a local app, so you need to figure out which test isn't using selenium and change it so it is, or set `Capybara.default_driver = :selenium` (or whatever you've named your instance of the driver that uses selenium) so all tests are using it

Comment: They all are using it, because they all work fine when I run them on their own. It's only if I try to run them all at once (via command prompt) that I get this issue. I suspect it's something with the visit ('/') command and maybe the browser already being open after another test has been ran?

Comment: @msmith1114 The fact the error message states 'rack-test' tells you they aren't all using selenium -- As a guess you're probably setting Capybara.current_driver - and not default_driver, and have included capybara/rspec which adds a hook that resets the driver to default_driver after every test so your first test always runs with selenium but after that they don't - Set the default_driver as I stated in my answer and your error will go away.

Comment: That did work, thanks. I guess I was doing what you told me and each test was using Current_driver, it makes sense though!